# Referencing to a pointer member in a different class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, member

I have a `Note` and a `Track` class which both `*generator` member. When I create new `Note` objects I want to link the `generator` member of `Note` to that of `Track` but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Generator {
public:
    virtual float getSample(int sample)=0;
};

class Note {
public:

    Generator *generator; // THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING ME TROUBLE
    Note(Generator *aGen){
        generator = aGen;
    }
};

class Synth  : public Generator{
public:
    virtual float getSample(int sample);
    int varA;
    int varB;
    Synth(){
        varA = 5;
        varB = 8;
    }
};


float Synth::getSample(int sample){
    varA = sample;
    varB = 3;

    return 0;
}

class Track {
public:
    Generator *generator;
    Track(){
        generator = new Synth();
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Track track = Track();
    cout << "test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought of doing something like this, but it's not working:

```
Track track = Track();
Note n = Note(&track.generator);
```

**Error**

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
prog.cpp:48:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘Note::Note(Generator**)’ 
prog.cpp:48:35: note: candidates are: 
prog.cpp:13:5: note: Note::Note(Generator*) 
prog.cpp:13:5: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Generator**’ to ‘Generator*’ prog.cpp:9:7: note: Note::Note(const Note&) 
prog.cpp:9:7: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Generator**’ to ‘const Note&’ prog.cpp:48:10: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable] - See more at: http://ideone.com/E38ibe#sthash.V3QMcYJQ.dpuf
```

[Live example here.](http://ideone.com/E38ibe)

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear about what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the compiler is telling you, this line:

```
Note n = Note(&track.generator);
```

Tries to construct a `Note` and supply a `Generator**` to its constructor (since `track.generator` has type `Generator*`, `&track.generator` has type `Generator**`).

However, your `Note` class constructor accepts a `Generator*`, not a `Generator**`. Just do this instead (notice, that *copy-initialization* is unnecessary here, rather use *direct-initialization*):

```
Track track;
Note n(track.generator);
```

Answer (score 1):

`track.generator` is a pointer to `Generator` already, you don't need to take its address.

Just stay with

```
Node n = Node(track.generator); // without & operator
```

Updated code: http://ideone.com/fAA4JX