# C++ downcasting

Tags: c++, interface, casting, member

This question is a followup on [what I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186114/referencing-to-a-pointer-member-in-a-different-class)

Synth implements Generator and Track has a generator member (which has a Synth in it). What I want to do is something like:

```
Track track = Track();
cout << track.generator.varA << endl;
```

But this doesn't work so I'm guessing I have to somehow cast generator to Synth first, before I can access any synthesizer methods or members and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: If you need a cast, then that implies a better design would be for `Track` to have a pointer to a `Synth`, rather than to the base class.  Unless you're doing something exotic, a downcast is usually a sign of a suboptimal design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `generator` is a pointer, so you cannot use the `.` operator to access a member of the pointed object, as you do here:

```
track.generator.varA // ERROR!
```

Secondly, since you want a pointer to a *derived class* and you have a pointer to a base class, you should use `dynamic_cast<>` to get one (unless you are sure the object pointed to is an instance of the derived class, in that case you can use `static_cast<>`):

```
Synth* p = dynamic_cast<Synth*>(track.generator);
if (p != nullptr)
{
    cout << p->varA << endl;
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked. One more question: do I need to somehow delete `*p` when I'm done with it?

Comment: @Sled: Everything that was allocated with `new` must eventually deallocated with `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

To downcast to a derived type when you're sure the base pointer you have is really that derived type, do:

`static_cast<Derived*>(myBasePointer)`